# GPRS communication

Tags: modem, gsm

I want to set up communication between GSM/GPRS modem and a remote server or PC. How to do that? Do we need some application on PC which will communicate to the GSM modem. I want 2 way commuinication. I want to interface GSM/GPRS modem with some microprocessor which has some LCD display. Can anybody help me in this.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about that "some microprocessor with some display" device?  Your options will probably be limited by what exactly that external device is capable of supporting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have a microcontroller board which has keypad and an LCD attached to it. So what I want to do, I want to interface GSM/GPRS modem to this board and want to communicate to the remote server that is a Desktop computer. So I want to know how to do that. What I think, I have to make a GUI application on the remote server that will communicate to GSM/GPRS modem. I have no experience in this so I want to know this thing. I want 2-way communication.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad and covers a range of technologies.

**Communicating with a GSM Modem**

A GSM modem will connect to a computer using a serial or USB port. You can open the serial port and talk with it. Since you didn't specify platform, I can't suggest how to do that. In c#, you would use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class. You use the standard [AT* command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) for various operations with it.

**Communicating with a GPRS modem**

A GPRS modem connected to external device will normally be on internet. If you know the IP address of target device, you can use TCP/IP sockets for communicating with it.

> I want to interface GSM/GPRS modem
>   with some microprocessor

Not sure what exactly you mean by that but if you want to program a processor for GPRS/GSM communication, you will need to understand that processor and write or buy a TCP/IP stack.

Comment: what kind of application i need to develop on the remote server side, so that GPRS modem will be able to communicate to that application?

Comment: means it should be a GUI application obviously.. which language we can use to develop that? and using gprs how much speed we can attain?

Answer (score 1):

I think as the previous answer says you need to be more specific:

If you want to communicate with the GPRS modem itself, then you generally need a physical connection between whatever machine wants to talk to the modem and you would use regular modem AT commands (you could conceivably want to remotely control a modem but I am guessing this is unlikely).

More likely you want to communicate between a device (e.g. a computer) connected to the GPRS modem and a remote server. Provided your GPRS modem is working correctly you simply need to treat the GPRS modem as you would a regular interconnect connection. In other words your computer will now be able to use its browser (for example) to connect to a remote server just as it would if you were connected by a cable to your local LAN.